# How to select from table with one to many relation to be one row result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

Restaurant

```
+---------------+----------------+
| restaurant_id | Restaurant name|
+---------------+----------------+
| 1             | KFC            |
| 2             | McD            |
+----+---------------------------+
```

Cuisine

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| cuisine_id    | restaurant_id | cuisine        |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| 1             | 1             | Fastfood       |
| 2             | 1             | Fried Chicken  |
| 3             | 2             | Fastfood       |
| 4             | 2             | Burger         |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Is it possible to get data like this =

```
+---------------+----------------+------------------------+
| restaurant_id | Restaurant name| Cuisine                |
+---------------+----------------+------------------------+
| 1             | KFC            |Fastfood, Fried Chicken |
| 2             | McD            |Fastfood, Burger        |
+----+---------------------------+------------------------+
```

with a single query?
Or should I do it via php (select table Restaurant first > foreach loop > select Cuisine by Restaurant id > parsing into new array).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this:

```sql
SELECT r.restaurant_id, r.Restaurant_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.cuisine ORDER BY c.cuisine)
FROM Restaurant AS r
LEFT JOIN Cuisine AS c ON r.restaurant_id = c.restaurant_id
GROUP BY  r.restaurant_id, r.Restaurant_name
```

**Note:** The `ORDER BY` clause within `GROUP_CONCAT` is only necessary if you want an *ordered* comma separated list of `cuisine` names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT c.restaurant_id,r.restaurant_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cuisine)
FROM Restaurant r
INNER JOIN Cuisine c ON c.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id 
GROUP BY c.restaurant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Restaurant.restaurant_id, Restaurant.Restaurant_name, GROUP_CONCAT(Cuisine.cuisine)
FROM Restaurant
LEFT JOIN Cuisine ON Restaurant.restaurant_id = Cuisine.restaurant_id
GROUP BY Restaurant.restaurant_id, Restaurant.Restaurant_name
```